# Cannot be applied to operands 'string' and 'decimal'

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm currently writing some tests to see if values in a Dictionary match up. An example is 'TestOperatorMatchNotFoundIfValueNotNumeric' etc. I have successfully written the tests when comparing a string to a string but now I have to check if the value is not numeric (making it invalid)

I have tried to use the logic used in previous tests with some tweaks but I'm getting error message'Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'decimal'. Below is the code I'm working on with the two error messages coming at line 8 and 9. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 public bool IsMatch(Dictionary<String, String> variableData)
    {
        decimal outputValue;
        bool isANumber = Decimal.TryParse("StringValue", out outputValue);

        if (variableData.ContainsKey(this.value1Name))
        {
            if (comparisonOperator == "==")
            {
                if (variableData[this.value1Name] == this.value2Literal) //Error Msg
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (variableData[this.value1Name] != this.value2Literal) //Error Msg
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What is type of `value2Literal` and `comparisonOperator `

Comment: Edit, value2Literal is a decimal and comparisonOperator a String.

Comment: Then am 100 % sure problem is not in above code. post the place where you get error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant compare 1.00 == "1.00", you can Convert.ToDecimal("1.00") and compare that. 
but I do not recomend that.

You see your dictionary has string value.

so youre code would become

```
Convert.ToDecimal(variableData[this.value1Name]) == this.value2Literal
```